# Proof verification: Linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

**Question**: Let $S:U \longrightarrow V$ and $T: V \longrightarrow W$ be linear maps. Prove that $\operatorname{Range}(TS) \subseteq \operatorname{Range}(T)$.

**Proof**: Let $u \in U$, $v \in V$, $w \in W$ be some vectors. Suppose that $$w = T(S(u)) = T(v).$$ This means that $w \in \operatorname{Range}(TS)$, since $w$ is in the image of the composition $TS$. But then $w$ must be in the image of $T$, so $w \in \operatorname{Range}(T)$. Since $w \in \operatorname{Range}(TS)$ and also $w \in \operatorname{Range}(T)$, we have that $\operatorname{Range}(TS) \subseteq \operatorname{Range}(T)$.

(I am unsure about this proof since I didn't rely on the fact that $S$ and $T$ are linear maps and I don't know if my choice of vectors applies generally.)

Comment: It seems good to me. $\text{im}(TS) = \text{im}(T|_{im(S)})$. This does not rely on the fact that $T$ and $S$ are linear mapping.

Comment: This logic is not correct.You should start with  an element that belongs to range of $TS$ and then show that it belongs to range of $T$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh I didn't catch this point. Just start from the point that $(\forall w)(w\in \text{im}(TS) \to (\exists u \in U)(w=TS(u))$. This suggests also that there exists a $v\in V$ such that $v=S(u)$ and $w=T(v)$. Now $w\in \text{im}(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has nothing to do with linearity. This holds for any such mappings.

Start of the proof is not correct.

To show $\operatorname{Range}(TS)\subseteq\operatorname{Range}(T)$, start with letting $w\in W$ such that $w\in \operatorname{Range}(TS)$. Then $w=TS(u)$ for some $u\in U$. Then $w=T(S(u))\implies w\in\operatorname{Range}(T)$. Thus it is proved.

Comment: Exact to the extent that I could possibly consider.

Comment: What do you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

I'd adjust the last sentence to read "when $w\in\operatorname{Range}TS$, then also $w\in\operatorname{Range} T$. Also, $v,w$ are not arbitrary. They depend on your choice of $u$. The point is that if $w$ is the image of an arbitrary vector $u$ under $TS$, then it's also the image of the (not arbitrary) vector $S(u)$ under $T$.
And you're right, the claim is true for arbitrary maps on arbitrary sets. Them being linear maps isn't necessary at all.

Comment: The starting point of OP's proof is not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Right, I changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you prove this type of inclusion then enumerate an element from 'left' and show that this is also in 'right'. That will work for arbitrarily elements.

Suppose $w\in \operatorname{Range}(TS)$. Then $TS(u)=w$ for some $u$ in $U$. $TS(u)=T(S(u))=T(v)=w$ for some $v\in V$.i.e, $w\in \operatorname{Range}(T)$. It follows that $\operatorname{Range}(TS)\subseteq \operatorname{Range}(T)$.